# Is there a way to unbind .accdb from TFS "silently"

Tags: vba, tfs, ms-access-2010

The only way to unbind .accdb from TFS I know is compacting:

`msaccess.exe myproject.accdb /compact`

When I do that, Access asks me to confirm deleting from Source Code Control(Dialog yes/no box. Can't provide a screenshot rn.)

Is it possible to programmatically compact a database without having that confirmation? Or maybe there is another way to unbind a database from TFS?

Access 2010 v14

UPD1: Here is the screenshot.

[image: "Would you like to remove the compacted database from Source Code Control?"]

UPD2: It was SourceSafe with my language pack, now it's Source Code Control. My bad, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Install Instructions` in the following link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6840

To remove this download:

1. Open **Control Panel**.
2. Double-click **Add or Remove Program**s.
3. In the list of currently installed programs, select **Microsoft Office Access Developer Extensions**.
4. Click **Remove**, and then click **Yes** to confirm that you want to remove the program.

Comment: I use MS Access and VBA for the project. So I don't have any solution files. It's just an Access' `.accdb` file which is bound to TFS with Source Code Control.

Comment: It seems you have to enable the developer extensions within Access to make Source code control work, so how about disable the extension?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to disable it beside uninstallation.

Comment: Check the `Install Instructions` in the following link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6840. To remove this download:
1. Open Control Panel.
2. Double-click Add or Remove Programs.
3. In the list of currently installed programs, select Microsoft Office Access Developer Extensions.
4. Click Remove, and then click Yes to confirm that you want to remove the program.